# How to submit data by a button click in a database using jdbc?

Tags: java, database, swing

I am working on a project in java(swing components).i have created a form which consists of a button and a text box.And after entering the value in the textbox and clicking the submit button ,i want the value to be entered in the database .

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is much too broad and general for SO.  Please read the [faq] and [ask] for more information.

Comment: what you need is a tutorial, not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [this](http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/jdbc-insert-records.htm) tutorial it should give you an example of what you need. That being said, I think that you should also take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) tutorial from Oracle for a more comprehensive read.

Answer (score 1):

put this on your submit button Action Listener....

```
try{
Connection con = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";, "root", "root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
int i= st.executeUpdate("Insert into employee(empName,empAddress) values('"+value1+"','"+value2+"')");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data is successfully inserted into the database." );
st.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Before writing this code, too many things are necessary to make this work..